# SEO Title Tags Not Showing

Tags: titles, seo

We’re having a big issue with SEO data. Any link preview does not pull the entry title but the global site title. For example, [on this blog post](http://bridgepartnersconsulting.com/insights/detail/darby-greenwell-joins-bridge-partners-to-lead-analytics-practice), all link previews (Google, Twitter, Facebook, LinkedIn, etc) show just Bridge Partners as the title and not the page title of Darby Greenwell Joins Bridge Partners To Lead Analytics Practice. I have searched high and low for solutions to this problem. Can anyone help point me in the right direction? Thank you!

www.bridgepartnersconsulting.com

Comment: This question is not Craft-specific, and it's _very_ tempting to close it as "off-topic". However, there are some Craft-specific solutions which may help you. Can you at least confirm that your website was built with Craft?

Comment: It is a Craft site based on the X-Powered-By header.

Comment: Ethan, I would recommend you go back to your developer and tell them they did not add any SEO tags — Craft does not auto-generate this sort of thing (as every site has different needs), and it looks like your developer did not add them for you. I would also recommend the SEOmatic plugin, which makes SEO best practices very easy.

Comment: I take that back — you do have proper SEO tags, so I'm not sure why you're seeing an issue on your end. All looks good to me.

Answer (score 2):

It would be helpful if you post your code instead of a link, as the metadata available on the linked page may change.

A few considerations:

1. Make sure your page is outputting metadata for each of the services you mention. It looks like you are outputting some basic and Open Graph metadata, but you don't appear to have any Twitter Card metadata. I've added a list of common meta tags that should help address most social sharing scenarios below.
2. Most of the services you have document which tags matter to them and some even have debugger tools that can help you troubleshoot.

   - [Open Graph Protocol](http://ogp.me)
   - [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/)
   - [Twitter Card Spec](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/overview)
   - [Twitter Card validator](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator)
   - [LinkedIn Sharing](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en) uses the same Open Graph tags as Facebook
3. Make sure you consider caching. Sometimes, when you test your shared content the services you share it on will cache it. If you then update your content you may not see the updated version of your content in a link you have already shared until you break that cache.
4. Structured Data is also becoming an important type of metadata to add to your pages: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data
5. This stuff gets complicated to maintain directly in your templates very quickly. Several Craft plugins are available to help manage that complexity. [Sprout SEO](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/seo) and [SEOmatic](https://github.com/nystudio107/seomatic) are two SEO plugins that are well supported and try to address the majority of SEO best practices that you need to worry about.

**Common Meta Tags for Search and Social Sharing**

```
<!-- Search -->
<title></title>
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="robots" content="" />
<link rel='canonical' href='' />

<!-- Open Graph -->
<meta property='og:type' content='' />
<meta property='og:url' content='' />
<meta property='og:site_name' content='' />
<meta property='og:title' content='' />
<meta property='og:description' content='' />
<meta property='og:image' content='' />
<meta property='og:image:width' content='' />
<meta property='og:image:height' content='' />
<meta property='og:image:type' content='' />
<meta property='og:author' content='' />
<meta property='og:publisher' content='' />

<!-- Twitter Card -->
<meta property='twitter:card' content='' />
<meta property='twitter:url' content='' />
<meta property='twitter:site' content='' />
<meta property='twitter:creator' content='' />
<meta property='twitter:title' content='' />
<meta property='twitter:description' content='' />
<meta property='twitter:image' content='' />
```

Comment: The passing mentions of Sprout SEO and SEOmatic are the only things keeping this thread from being closed as "off topic".